# Wordpress - Video Popup Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I created my own WP Theme. I added a JS Carousel. In each part of the carousel I have a description and Video below it. You can see it here at www.tvstartup.com The problem is that the video that it suppose to pop up to play does not always work. In some cases it does and in others it does not. 
here is a sample of the code:

```
<div class="carousel_item">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/final/internet-tv.png" alt="Internet TV" />
    </div>
    <div class="caption">
        <h2>Internet TV</h2>
        <p>Ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim  veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehender.</p>
        <div class="btn-wrap">
            <div class="button">
                PRICING
            </div>
            <div class="button" id="contact">
                CONTACT US
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="internetvideocontainer" style="display:none;">
            <a href="#" onclick="popup('internetvideocontainer'); stopinternetvideo();" style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 30px; color: red;">Click to Close</a>
            <video width="700" height="400" id="internetvideoplayer" controls>
                <source src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ? >/images/videos/WelcometoTvStartUp.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
             <a href="#" onclick="popup('internetvideocontainer'); stopinternetvideo();" style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 30px; color: red;">Click to Close</a>
        </div>                                                 
        <a href="#" style="cursor: pointer" onclick="popup('internetvideocontainer'); playinternetvideo();">
             <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/watchImg.png" alt="click to see video" class="internettvtumbnail" style="padding-top:45px; width:250; height:150px;">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

any help,

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way

```
            function load_my_script() {
                wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
            }
            add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_my_script' );
```

and change all '$(' to 'jQuery('

---

The Not So right Way
Add the following code in the header.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The latter will work for you but I would suggest you change your code to avoid further issues.

Comment: i fixed them now can you please help me on my question

Comment: Wonderful! see the changes now. modify the Chromecast  code as 'onclick="popup('chromevideocontainer');$('#chromevideoplayer')[0].play()'

Comment: it still does not work i think i should use a different video popup

Answer (score 0):

convert all your jquery statements

```
$(.....
```

to

```
jQuery(....
```

Comment: there is no jquery in my example

Comment: open http://tvstartup.com/ in chrome and check the dev console for error. '$(... is not defined' This happends when jQuery is not laoded. you can also add the following into your functions.php file - function load_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_my_script' );